# Make class element bigger on hover

Tags: html, css, hover, css-transitions

I've set a class for the "next" and "previous" functions on my page and what I would like to do is make it bigger (and the other elements would move aside at the same time) when hovering. That's not very clear.. So for example :

My mouse is hovering on the NEXT button, at this moment I'd like for this button to get bigger. So that means it'll take more space, hence the other elements (back and top) moving aside.

I'm just not sure if I can do it with a class and not an id? I've tried putting .next:hover{width:120%} but it didn't do anything

Here's my code

```css
#pager{
width:100%;
height:50px;
margin-top:20px;
margin-bottom:20px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
 
#pagination{
margin:auto;
width:572px;
height:30px;
text-align:center;
}
 
.pagicon, .next{
display:inline;
}

 
.pagicon a, .next{
font-size:11px;
padding:5px;
margin:5px;
color:{color:Pagination};
background:{color:Pagination background};
border-radius:{text:Border radius};
}
 
.pagicon a:hover, .next:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
color:{color:Bold};
background:{color:Hover};  
}
 
.pagicon i, .next i{
color:{color:Icon};
font-size:15px;
margin:5px;
text-decoration:none;
}
 
.pagicon:hover i, .next:hover i{
color:{color:Bold};
}
```

```html
<div id="pager">
 
<div id="pagination">
<span class="pagicon">
<a href="{PreviousPage}"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> BACK </a>
</span>
 
<span class="pagicon">
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></i> TOP </a>
</span>
 

<a class="next" href="{NextPage}"> NEXT <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>
 
</div>
```

(in the actual website there are boxes around the buttons)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it with JS. Have a look below. I have used `onmouseover` and `onmouseout`. You can change the font size on hover. it is currently at 70px.

```js
function hoverFn(classnm) {
  document.getElementById(classnm).style.fontSize = "70px";
}

function nothoverFn(classnm) {
  document.getElementById(classnm).style.fontSize = "1em";
}
```

```css
#pager {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#pagination {
  margin: auto;
  width: 572px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.pagicon,
.next {
  display: inline;
}

.pagicon a,
.next {
  font-size: 11px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  color: {
    color: Pagination
  }
  ;
  background: {
    color: Pagination background
  }
  ;
  border-radius: {
    text: Border radius
  }
  ;
}

.pagicon a:hover,
.next:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: {
    color: Bold
  }
  ;
  background: {
    color: Hover
  }
  ;
}

.pagicon i,
.next i {
  color: {
    color: Icon
  }
  ;
  font-size:15px;
  margin:5px;
  text-decoration:none;
}

.pagicon:hover i,
.next:hover i {
  color: {
    color: Bold
  }
  ;
}
```

```html
<div id="pager">

  <div id="pagination">
    <span class="pagicon">
<a href="{PreviousPage}"  id= "back" onmouseover="hoverFn('back')" onmouseout="nothoverFn('back')"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> BACK </a>
</span>

    <span class="pagicon">
<a href="#" id="top" onmouseover="hoverFn('top')" onmouseout="nothoverFn('top')"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></i> TOP </a>
</span>


    <a class="next" id="next" href="{NextPage}" onmouseover="hoverFn('next')" onmouseout="nothoverFn('next')"> NEXT <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Hope it helps. Mark as answer if it does please!

Comment: Thank you that's awesome! I would really like to get more into the code to understand what you did though but thank you!